# Should the breaker for a shed circuit be in the panel or in the shed?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I want to run 15amp electric service to a shed by my pond from a nearby sub-panel.  My question is do I install the shed's 15amp circuit breaker at the sub-panel (with a disconnect switch at the shed?), or if not do I install it at the shed? Also is 40 amp service to the sub-panel adequate?[image: Shed Electric Service] I attached a drawing of the configuration.

Comment: I would recommend 2-2-2-4 aluminum from house to sub-panel - it is 90A rated and cheaper than even 40A copper wire. (use a 60A breaker, cheaper than 90A). Aluminum is perfectly fine as large feeder, plus subpanel lugs are made of aluminum.  Since you are enlarging wire considerably for the 15A feed, I'd run 6-6-6 aluminum or just more 2-2-2-4 (depending on price).  Terminate it at a disconnect switch (merely because it's a cheap way to adapt large AL wire to small Cu wire to go to the outlet).

Comment: I've already purchased the 8ga copper wire.

Answer (score 1):

For a 15 or 20 amp circuit put the breaker in the sub then a standard light switch at the shed. A switch is code compliant. The switch has to have an off position marked on the switch(not a 3 way). No need for a fancy disconnect in this case.
After looking closer at your drawing you might want to consider going aluminum and 240v with a sub panel there then a main breaker could be the disconnect you would need 4 wire and grounding rod. That #8 copper is going to be spendy compared to aluminum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have already purchased the 8ga copper wire.  So at the shed should I run the service to the on/off switch, or to a GFCI outlet first? Can the switch also control the ceiling light, or be separate to act as a disconnect?

Comment: Yes, +1 Ed.  I think OP could pull it off with 6-6-6 on a lone 120V circuit. As far as adapting aluminum to copper at the shed, either Ilsco MAC Block Connectors (which take up to three #12 copper + a #6AL), or a cheap $15 pullout style disconnect just for its aluminum-rated lugs LOL.  As far as the copper if you can't tan't take it back, right now shortages and all, you can get top dollar for good wires on Craigslist and Facebook marketplace.

Comment: If you have the wire well you will need to downsize if you use a standard switch as they can not handle more than 10awg if cu/Al listed ( pigtail down to 12 or 14 ) if you use 12 you can use a 20 amp breaker, Yes any receptacles will require GFCI protection. I use both dead face (no receptacle) and standard GFCI receptacles on the load terminals.